# What's the synonym word when you DO NOT get on with someone?

Tags: synonyms

Could anyone tell me what is the synonym word for describing when **you don't get along with someone**. the word must include 5 letters. Thank you

Comment: Is this for a crossword puzzle?

Comment: yes! and then I have to use that word in a sentence...

Comment: Clash. (If the puzzle has a prize I want 50%!)